# Change source attribute on image_tag Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the following is my attempt to switch images in Rails :

The controller's update action:

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    @peaks = Peak.all 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_path }
        format.js { render action: :show, format: :js }
      else
         format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the .js.erb file:

```
<% @peaks.each do |peak|%>
$('#<%= if @user.peaks.include(peak)?  peak.id : ""
    end %>').attr( "src" , "<%= image_path "badges/chevron-10.png", :id => peak.id %>" );
<% end %>
```

However, I'm getting the following error in the server output:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong argument type Peak (expected Module)):
3:
4: <% @peaks.each do |peak|%>
5: $('#<%= if @user.peaks.include(peak)?  peak.id : ""
6:         end %>').attr( "src" , "<%= image_path "badges/chevron-10.png", :id => peak.id %>" );
7: <% end %>
```

Peak is a model used in the app, so I am unsure as to what fix is necessary. Thanks. J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few errors in your ternary:

1. The method is `include?` not `include`
2. You must add a space between the condition and the `?`
3. You need neither `if` nor `end`
4. `image_path` doesn't accept two arguments (keep only the url)

So try this instead:

```
<% @peaks.each do |peak|%>
  $('#<%= @user.peaks.include?(peak) ? peak.id : "" %>').attr("src", "<%= image_path("badges/chevron-10.png") %>");
<% end %>
```

The above code will get rid of your current error, but could fail if the ternary evaluates to `false` and returns `""` (because no element in the DOM will match `id = ""`).

To avoid this i will recommend skipping the ternary and using a regular `if` statement, like this:

```
<% @peaks.each do |peak| %>
  <% if @user.peaks.include?(peak) %>
    $('#<%= peak.id %>').attr("src", "<%= image_path("badges/chevron-10.png") %>");
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: YES!! I didn't even notice my syntax mistake,  I went with your last suggestion and it works flawlessly, now I just have to switch it back if it's unchecked. Thanks ever so much, peace. :)